# Load two requireJs app in single page

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am new to requirejs . I am creating an app. My issue is that i am concerned about the conflict between requirejs version using my app and requirejs version already running on the page.

So to test this problem i have created the two apps using two different version. I am printing the version number in both apps.

**Directory structure**

```
/require
-/libs
--require.js(version 2.1.19)
-main.js
/require-test
-/libs
--require.js(version 2.1.20)
-main-test.js
```

I used the following code to run the both apps

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/require-test/libs/require.js" data-main="/require-test/main-test" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/require/libs/require.js" data-main="/require/main" > </script>
```

Both require.js files is getting load. 
Problem is only require-test app is running. It prints the correct version of require.js. 
If i switch the order of apps. First app is getting load everytime.
What is conflict? How to solve this issue?

Comment: You can't load the same library twice, on a single page.

Comment: @Cerbrus Is there workaround for this ?  i have a native app, There  will be conflict on webpages which are already running requirejs app on their page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the 2.x series I don't recall running into a case where something that worked in a previous version did not work in a newer one. So there shouldn't be any problem loading all the code with the latest version in the 2.x series.

What is likely to become a problem is if the two applications use significantly different versions of the same library (e.g. jQuery 1.3 vs 2.x). The solution for this is to use [contexts](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion).

Answer (score 1):

Use the require script once, and in the 'data-main' file merge the config data so that it loads the necessary stuff for both libraries in the one file.

Comment: I dont have control over requirejs app on user page, I can only change the code in my app. So both app needs its own require script.

Comment: I think thats the problem then, you should have sole control over, how you use require for your application. I don't think require supports having multiple base urls.